# What’s the original sense of the term “alveary”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

Lexicographer [John Baret](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Baret) published, in about 1574, a dictionary of the English, Latin, and French languages, with occasional illustrations from the Greek. The dictionary  was called *An Alvearie, or Triple Dictionarie*.

Nowadays most dictionaries define the term alveary as beehive while  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/alveary)  provides only the following definition:

> A repository, especially of knowledge or information. Originally as the name of a dictionary encompassing several languages.

The term derives from Latin [alvearium](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/alvearium#Latin), from *alveus* (“hollow, belly, vessel, beehive”).

Apparently the term alveary in the multi-dictionary sense was an English usage (I couldn’t find this usage in Latin or other related languages).

My question is:

Did John Baret first introduce the term alveary into the English language with his dictionary or was the term already in use with the “beehive” sense at that time?

Comment: The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5922?redirectedFrom=alveary#eid) gives 1574 as the first reference _1574   J. Baret (title)    An aluearie or triple dictionarie, in Englishe, Latin, and French._. // The first reference to beehive is 1623. // The first reference to the auditory canal (now obs.) is 1615.

Comment: The above comment gives the facts, but it's worth bearing in mind that many educated Britons would have a good knowledge of Latin and be familiar with the Latin word; it was common to transport words from Latin into English (writers such as Spenser and Milton did it frequently, assuming the reader would know the sense from the Latin). Hence it would be less a new coinage than a transposition of a word with which Baret's contemporaries would be familiar.

Comment: An early buzzword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***'Alvearium' in English before Baret***

The earliest English-language treatment I've been able to find of *alvearie*—or more precisely, of its Latin antecedents—is from Thomas Elyot, [*The Dictionary of Syr Thomas Eliot Knyght*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A21313.0001.001/1:7.17?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=Aluear*) (1538), which consists of English definitions of Latin words:

> **Aluearium**, et **Alueare**, a place where hiues be sette. also a stocke of hyues.

According to Elyot, the word for the hive itself (as opposed to the setting place for multiple hives) is *alueus* or *aluus*:

> **Alueus** et **aluus**, a hyue for bees, a vessaile to washe in, the bealy of any thing that lacketh lyfe. sometyme it signifieth a shyppe.

Although Elyot's entry for *alueus* is clearly more varied and potentially figurative than his entry for *aleurium*, it doesn't suggest any application to a repository of knowledge or information.

Also antedating Baret's 1574 dictionary title is Richard Huleot, [*Huloets Dictionarie Newelye Corrected, Amended, Set in Order and Enlarged*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A03825.0001.001/1:10.76?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=Aluear*) (1572), which has these relevant entries:

> *Hiue for bees*. Alueus, Aluus, ui. foe. ge. *Vne ruche de mousches a miel. S.* Apiarium, ij. n. g. *A place where bees are set*. *Vn lieu des mousches a miel. S.*
>
> *Hiue where the bees make their hony, or the place where the hyues be*. Aluear, siue Alueare, & **Aluearium**, ij. n. ge. *Vne ruche ou les mouches font leur miel, ou le lieu ou sont les ruches. S.*
>
> *Hiue made after the shape of a shippe*. Naustibulū, Alueus ad similitudinem nauis factus. Cal.
>
> *Hiue maker*.← **Aluearius**.*

Regrettably, Huleot doesn't provide a Latin word for *dictionary*, but there is no indication that *alvearie* had any currency in the sense of "multilanguage dictionary" as of 1572.

---

***'Alveary' in early English-only dictionaries***

The earliest occurrence I've found of of *alvearie* as an defined word in an English-only dictionary is in Henry Cockeram, [*The English Dictionarie: Or, an Interpreter of Hard English Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5PhmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22A%20Bee-%22&f=false), second edition (1626), which spells it differently in two separate places:

> ***Aluearie,*** A Bee-hiue.
>
> a Bee-hiue, *Aluiary*

Thomas Blount, [*Glossographia Or a Dictionary: Interpreting All Such Hard Words, Whether Hebrew, Greek, Latin, Italian, Spanish, French, Teutonick, Belgick, British or Saxon, as Now Are Used in Our Refined English Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QctmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA4-IA1&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22or%20the%20place%20where%20Bees%22&f=false) (1656) includes a definition of the term that includes both its literal apiary meaning and its potential metaphorical meanings:

> **Alveary** (*alvearium*) a Bee-hive or the place where Bees or Bee-hives stand. It may be used metaphorically for a house full of Inhabitants, a Library full of Books, or the like.

Edward Phillips, [*The New World of English Words, or a Generall Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RR9lAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT120&dq=%22first+draught+of+a+picture%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_jd_k_fHQAhUU8GMKHZwpBswQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%22a%20Hive%20of%20Bees%22&f=false) (1658), however, reports only the simple sense of the term:

> ***Alveary,*** (Lat.) a Hive of Bees.

And Elisha Coles, [*An English Dictionary: Explaining the Difficult Terms That Are Used in Divinity, Husbandry, Physick, Phylosophy, Law, Navigation, Marhematicks, and Other Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=n_5mAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP11&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22Bee-hives%22&f=false) (1676) follows suit:

> ***Alveary,*** *l.* Bee-hives.

John Worlidge, [*Systema Agriculturæ; The Mstery of Husbandry Discovered*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bc81DWw_WowC&pg=PA313&dq=%22Alveary,+a+Hive+of+Bees%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBhc3p_aDsAhXDuZ4KHX-NAYwQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Alveary%2C%20a%20Hive%20of%20Bees%22&f=false) (16775) conveniently distinguishes in consecutive entries between the similar terms *alveary* and *apiary*:

> ***Alveary***, a Hive of Bees.
>
> ***Apiary***, a place or Court where Bees are kept.

This gives *alveary* the meaning that *alueus* had in Elyot's 1538 dictionary, and it gives *apiary* a meaning very similar to the one that *aluearium* had in Elyot's dictionary.

---

The earliest English-language use of *alvearium* that I found in a series of searches of the Early English Books Online database uses the word in a completely unexpected (but logically related) way. From Helkiah Crooke, [*Mikrokosmographia A Description of the Body of Man*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A19628.0001.001/1:7.15.12?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div3;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=Aluear*) (1615):

> But the Cauity which is next vnto the hole of Hearing wherein the eare-wax is, is cald [word or words in non-Latin alphabet] ***Aluearium***, and the bitter waxe it selfe *Aphrodisaeus* calles [word or words in non-Latin alphabet].

Clearly the chamber where ear wax collects was named *aluearium* in honor of the wax-making chamber of a beehive.

That meaning remained in English for at least a century, as we see in examples from Stephen Blancard, [*The Physical Dictionary, Wherein the Terms of Anatomy, the Names and Causes of Diseases, Chyrurgical Instruments and Their Use; Are Accurately Described*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bTcpJsjZTK0C&pg=PA97&dq=%22unseemly+Distemper,+which+is+wont%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE1POEnvTaAhVrw1QKHQIxBLwQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22cavity%20of%20the%20inward%20Ear%22&f=false), second edition (1693):

> ***Alvearium,*** the cavity of the inward Ear, near the passage which conveys the Sound, where that yellow and bitter excrementitious stuff is bred.

and from John Harris, [*Lexicon Technicum: Or, An Universal English Dictionary of Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TnNkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT131&dq=%22large+Earthen+Pan+unglazed+in+a+great+Fire%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia_ZKXsenrAhVJgp4KHV0zCZoQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Alvearium%22&f=false) (1704), a lexicographer who clearly didn't invent the wording he used:

> **ALVEARIUM**, is the Cavity of the inward Ear, near the Passage which conveys the Sound, where that yellow and bitter excrementitious Stuff is bred, called *Ear-Wax*.

The same entries appear at least as late as the [seventh edition of Blancard's *Physical Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zY1hAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22elements+in+the+blood+or+nervous+juice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiolKuv9PHQAhWFiFQKHWcgCTwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22cavity%20of%20the%20inward%20Ear%22&f=false) (1726) and the [fourth edition of Harris's *Lexicon Technicum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0GdEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT456&dq=%22weight+12+grains+if+there+be+another%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMtvfLsOnrAhVFgp4KHU99BJYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Alvearium%22&f=false) (1725)—although none of the seventeenth-century dictionaries of hard words cited earlier note the usage.

---

***Baret's responsibility for the 'multiple-language dictionary' meaning of 'alveary'***

Perhaps the clearest explanation of Baret's responsibility for introducing the sense of multiple-language dictionary comes from Baret himself, as noted in Joseph Shipley, [*Dictionary of Early English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=enmvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22Alveary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3ndrE_6DsAhXDGDQIHUmnBg8Q6AEwA3oECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Alveary%22&f=false) (1955):

> **alveary.** A company of busy workers; a monumental work, such as an encyclopedia. (From Latin *alvearium*, a range of beehives; *alveus*, a hollow vessel, hence a beehive. Also Latin *alvus*, womb; hence English *alvary*, womb, lap, as in Barnfield's CASSANDRA, 1595: *From his soft bosom, th' alvary of bliss*.) Baret in 1580, used the word *alveary* of an interlingual dictionary (English, Latin, French, and Greek), *which, for the apt similitude between the good scholars and diligent bees in gathering their wax and honey into their hive I called then their alvearie*. ... By an equal similitude, anatomists call the hollow of the ear, where wax accumulates, the *alveaary*.

Robert Gordon, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9J9S_4PBrvcC&pg=PA77&dq=%22scholars+and+diligent+bees%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7paaXg6HsAhWKuZ4KHcK2BUEQ6AEwB3oECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22scholars%20and%20diligent%20bees%22&f=false) (1876) cites a bit more of Baret's comment in its entry for *alveary*:

> **Alveary,** *s.* {Lat. *alvearium* = beehive.} Book serving as a reportorium or thesaurus. *Obsolete.* [Source note:] Within a yeare or two, they had gathered together a great volume, which (for the apt similitude betweene the good scholars and diligent bees in gathering their wax and honie into their hive) I called them their *alvearie*: both for a memoriall by whom it was made, and also by this name to encourage other to the like diligence, for that they should not see their worthie praise for the same unworthwhilie drowned in oblivion.—*Barret, To the Reader*.

It seems very clear that the hive sense of *alvearium* was known to Latin-literate English writers of Baret's time and that he invented the application of the word to his multiple-language dictionary. At least through the end of the seventeenth century, however, the term *alveary* doesn't seem to have been widely understood to mean a dictionary, although it did by 1626 have some currency as a term for a beehive.

Still, it isn't clear to me that *alveary* had any meaning to the everyday English-speaking populace of England in the late sixteenth century, either before or after Baret's book appeared. My impression is that learned readers understood Baret's usage of *alvearie* in the figurative sense of "beehive," the greater number of relatively unlearned readers had no clear idea what it meant, and the vast majority of the English population (who couldn't read at all) had never heard anyone say the word *alveary* in any context.

Answer (score 3):

English readers in the 15th century would have possibly encountered the Latin word *alvearium* in Middle English texts. The word was associated with a beehive.

The first instance I find comes from the Middle English *Palladius*, a translation of the 5th century text *Opus Agriculturae* by Palladius. D. R. Howlett, [in a 1977 article in the peer-reviewed journal *Medium Aevum*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43628272), dates the Middle English translation to 1442-1443.

The word appears in Latin [as the title of a poem](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CME00114/1:4.5.7?rgn=div3;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=aluear*):

> De apibus inuestigandis & **aluearijs** purgandis. [Of Investigating Bees and Cleaning Beehives]

The poem itself describes how to find bees and rehome them (the *investigating*), and, once they've been taken, how to keep the hives with herbs and remove the butterflies. Here's a small excerpt from the latter:

> Now purge her hyues, sle the butterflie  /
> That in the malwes flouring wol abounde.
>
> [Now clean her hives, kill the butterfly / that in the mallow flowers will dwell plentifully.]

The word also appears in a 15th century Middle English to Latin dictionary, the *Promptorium Parvulorum* ([EEBO](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CME00028/1:4.1.8?rgn=div3;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=bees#hl1), [HathiTrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hc1ae7&view=1up&seq=262&q1=bees)), dated to around 1440 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promptorium_parvulorum)). This text was reprinted several times, including in 1499 ([LEME](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicons/26/details)). *Alveare* is used to define the word "hive":

> HYVE for bees. **Alveare**, **alvea∣rium**, C. F. apiarium.

So the usage of *alvearium* in texts for English audiences goes back at least to the mid-fifteenth century, and even there the association with beehives is strong.

Comment: This is very interesting, my query   is about the usage of English form of the term: alveary (or alvearie) in its early instances. It appears that it entered the English language in the “dictionary “ sense rather than the “beehive” sense. Is that so?